# If two poisson intervals overlap, does this affect the probabilities of $Y-X$?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have two homogenous poisson processes with rate $\lambda$. $X = N(0,t_2]$ and $Y=N(t_1,t_3]$.

I want to find the probability of $Y-X$.

I know how to do this for when the intervals don't overlap.By this, I mean $0 < t_2 < t_1 < t_3$ 
.

If they overlap (i.e. $0<t_1<t_2<t_3$), does this affect the probabilities? If so how?

Comment: You say you have two, are they independent?

Comment: I adjusted it. I hope that clarifies

Comment: @probablyme I am asking if overlapping affects independence/dependence and why

Comment: I think you are confusing random variables and events. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then it doesn't matter how much overlap there is in the time interval, they will still be independent. I think you are struggling over something like you have _one_ process and you are interest in the interval $A = (0,t_1)$, $B = (t_2,t_3)$, and $A\cap B$. You can also have _two_ processes where one depends on the other and then you want to analyze $A\cap B$.

Comment: If they overlap, then $X-Y=N(0,t_1)-N(t_2,t_3)$ where the summands are independent. Summarizing, $X-Y=N(0,t_{(1)})-sgn(t_3-t_2)N(t_{(2)},t_{(3)})$.

Comment: So overlap doesn't affect independence? And this is because they are separate counting processes?

Comment: Because they are independent counting processes. Yes, I believe so.

Comment: More explicitely, if $0<t_1<t_2<t_3$, use the fact that $$Y-X=N(t_1,t_2]+N(t_2,t_3]-N(0,t_1]-N(t_1,t_2]=N(t_2,t_3]-N(0,t_1]$$ and use the preceding case since $(t_2,t_3]\cap(0,t_1]=\varnothing$ hence $N(t_2,t_3]$ and $N(0,t_1]$ are independent. (This assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are based on a common unique counting process $N$, which is most probably the context of the exercise.)